# pandas to_sql() gives a SADeprecationWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

The `to_sql()` function in pandas is now producing a SADeprecationWarning.

`df.to_sql(name=tablename, con=c, if_exists='append', index=False )`

```
[..]/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1430: SADeprecationWarning:The Connection.run_callable() method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Use a context manager instead. (deprecated since: 1.4)
```

I was getting this even with `df.read_sql()` command, when running sql select statements. Changing it to the original `df.read_sql_query()` that it wraps around, got rid of it. I'm suspecting there would be some linkage there.

So, question is, how to do I write a dataframe table to SQL without it getting deprecated in a future release? What does "use a context manager" mean, how can I implement that?

Versions:
pandas: 1.1.5 | SQLAlchemy: 1.4.0 | pyodbc: 4.0.30 | Python: 3.8.0
Working with a mssql database.
OS: Linux Mint Xfce, 18.04. Using a python virtual environment.

If it matters, connection created like so:

```
conn_str = r'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(dbString).strip()
sqlEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str,echo=False, pool_recycle=3600)
c = sqlEngine.connect()
```

And after the db operation,

```
c.close()
```

Doing so keeps the main connection sqlEngine "alive" between api calls and lets me use a pooled connection rather than having to connect anew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try...

```
connection_string = r'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(dbString).strip()
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string, echo=False, pool_recycle=3600)
with engine.connect() as connection:
    df.to_sql(name=tablename, con=connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

This approach uses a `ContextManager`. The `ContextManager` of the engine returns a connection and automatically invokes `connection.close()` on it, [see](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html). Read more about `ContextManager` [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html). Another useful thing to know is, that a connection is a `ContextManager` as well and handles transactions for you. This means it begins and ends a transaction and in case of an error it automatically invokes a rollback.

Comment: Oh! well why didn't they say it that way ;)

Comment: while this answer is helpful for understanding context managers, this doesnt actually solve the issue. The issue is pandas itself is using a deprecated method regardless if the calling code is using a context manager.

Answer (score 5):

Update: according to the pandas team, this will be fixed in Pandas 1.2.4 which as of the time of writing has not been released yet.

Adding this as an answer since Google led here but the accepted answer is not applicable.

Our surrounding code that uses Pandas *does* use a context manager:

```
with get_engine(dbname).connect() as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql(stmt, conn, **kwargs)
    return df
```

In my case, this error is being thrown from within pandas itself, not in the surrounding code that *uses* pandas:

```
  /Users/tommycarpenter/Development/python-indexapi/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1430: SADeprecationWarning: The Engine.run_callable() method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Use the Engine.connect() context manager instead. (deprecated since: 1.4)
```

The snippet from pandas itself is:

```
def has_table(self, name, schema=None):
    return self.connectable.run_callable(
        self.connectable.dialect.has_table, name, schema or self.meta.schema
    )
```

I raised an issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40825